# Simple react forEach not returning the correct value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

I'm trying to understand why the following will not, for example, take input like **joe bloggs** and return 'Joe' (with an uppercase letter J) using a `forEach` function rather than a classic for loop (commented out).

I have the form as a simple component:

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    const SignupForm = () => {
      const onSubmit = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.closest('form').querySelector('input[name="name"]'),
          nameVal = name.value;
    
        // 1. Gets first name only if full name provided
        nameVal = nameVal.split(' ')[0];
    
        // 2. Capitalises name first letter only & lowercase the rest
        nameVal = nameVal.split('');
        /*for (let i = 0; i < nameVal.length; i++) {
          if (i == 0) {
            nameVal[i] = nameVal[i].toUpperCase();
          } else {
            nameVal[i] = nameVal[i].toLowerCase();
          }
        }*/
/* CODE BELOW HERE */
        nameVal.forEach((cur, i) => {
          console.log('cur', cur, 'i', i);
          return i == 0 ? cur.toUpperCase() : cur.toLowerCase();
        });
/* CODE ABOVE HERE */
    
        console.log('nameVal now', nameVal);
    
        nameVal = nameVal.join('');
        name.value = nameVal;
    
        console.log('test form submit', e.target, 'nameVal: ', nameVal);
      };
    
      return (
        <div id='em-signup-form'>
          <h2>Enter Details:</h2>
          <form id='prospect-form'>
            <label htmlFor='name'>Name:</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              name='name'
              placeholder='Name*'
              required='required'
              pattern='[a-zA-Z ]+'
              oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Invalid Name')"
              oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
            />
            <label htmlFor='email'>Email Address:</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              name='email'
              placeholder='Email*'
              required='required'
              pattern='[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$'
              oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Invalid Email')"
              oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
            />
            <input type='hidden' name='tag' value='randomTag' />
            <button type='submit' className='btn-std' onClick={onSubmit}>
              Add Subscriber
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default SignupForm;
```

Note the relevant part below:

```
nameVal.forEach((cur, i) => {
          console.log('cur', cur, 'i', i);
          return i == 0 ? cur.toUpperCase() : cur.toLowerCase();
        });
```

I thought that nothing was actually being changed here and that this is skipped passed, hence I changed it to the below:

```
nameVal.forEach((cur, i) => {
      console.log('cur', cur, 'i', i);
      i == 0 ? (cur = cur.toUpperCase()) : (cur = cur.toLowerCase());
    });
```

But still nothing. How can I get the code to work using a `forEach` function rather than a classic for loop? This should be seemingly simple although I'm still getting used to the ES6+ syntax rather than ES5.

I know there are also errors with `oninvalid` and `oninput` although I assume there's a better react approach to this - any ideas? Thanks for any help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `map` in order to modify the current array. Difference between both, [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/4-main-differences-between-foreach-and-map/#:%7E:text=forEach()%20does%20not%20mutate%20the%20array%20on%20which%20it%20is%20called.&text=The%20map()%20method%20returns,original%20array%20with%20the%20callback%20.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your main question is not about ReactJS, it is related to functional loop on an Array. Based on ES6+ the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function return a new array and doesn't mutate the given array. the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function just gets a callback function and run it over the given array.

So, for your case, you should use the *map* function like below:

```js
const Array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const newArray = Array.map(item => item + 2);
```

The `newArray` is now `[3, 4, 5, 6]`.